# automatic payment by paypal vault and store the credit card

Tags: paypal, recurring

i understand we can store our client credit card information by paypay restful api by vault.
My questions are:

1. I tried this solution already in my paypal sandbox and it looks fine. But before executing this payment, it seems no approval is needed from my client. Is it normal?
2. Can I store this card id and charge my client in the future? Can I schedule some scripts to charge my client on weekly basis without their approval by vault method?
   It is like recurring billing?
3. From this link
   https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments
   paypal said Direct Credit Card Payments is only available in US and UK.
   I am not in UK neither US.
   Can I use vault to charge my client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That is normal, you should get the approval when you are storing the card, explaining to the user what they are consenting to. Within the valid_until range as in https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/ , you should not need additional approval for charges.
2. You can store the card token and charge client in the future, in effect achieving something similar to recurring billing. https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs/issues/3#issuecomment-37940026
3. That is correct, you can only use direct credit card payments (which includes Vault) only in the US and UK for now.

Comment: hi Avi ,i have a question:
1.Earlier i was using sandbox cred to store fake card no. and it was working fine. it storing card and saying card state is 'ok'
2.Now i am using live cred ,used same fake card and its getting stored and state returned by paypal api is again 'ok',how paypal is storing that card in live  environment???